# How to conserve probability using a numerical integration scheme?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods

I have an iterative operator that conserves probability given by

$P_{n+1}(z_j) = \int_a^b P_B(x+z_j)P_n(x) dx$,

where $P_n$ is the PDF at time step $n$ and $P_B$ is a PDF that is fixed with compact support. $P_0$ is given and I have use the trapezoidal rule to approximate the integral. I then examine the matrix $A$ with entries defined as $A_{i,j} = \frac{1}{2}C_{i,j} P_B(x_i + z_j)*\Delta x$, where $C_{i,j}$ is the appropriate constant ($1$ or $2$). I have found that the columns of $A$ do not sum to $1$ which would mean that the probability is not being conserved.

What numerical method do I need to use to conserve probability? Do I need other constraints?